# Tooltip border is thicker in Microsoft Edge

Tags: html, css, microsoft-edge

I have a table which shows a value when I hover over it.

It looks like this in Chrome:

[image]

And like this in Microsoft Edge:

[image]

I didn't change anything on it, it is probably the default setting but I tried to make it look like in Chrome (slim border) on Edge too but without success.

When I inspect the element I can access the width and the height which are set as default on 1. So I can only change the dimension of the tooltip but not the border thickness.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

You can't control the `title` or `alt` tooltips. Those are drawn by the browser and that is the way Edge is doing it.

You can however add your own tooltips using some JavaScript/CSS and there are plenty of libraries that do that.